# Did the American Magical Community come to help during the Second Wizarding War?

Tags: harry-potter

It would be difficult not to notice the occurrence of the Second Wizarding War since it broke out by the fall of the **Ministry of Magic (MoM)** in the UK. Additionally, Voldemort's rise to power was compared to that of Grindelwald's that affected the wizarding community across the globe. So I'd assume that the **American Magical Community (AMC)** was aware of the magnitude of the Second Wizarding War and its supposed consequences if Voldemort had won.

Questions [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39432/why-didnt-the-other-schools-help-hogwarts) and [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58575/why-did-international-wizards-not-come-to-help-against-voldemort) talks about why the other [European] wizards (from Durmstrang and Beauxbatons), didn't come to aid during the Wizarding War.

However, I could not find anything that mentions the role AMC played during the war against Voldemort.

So, was the AMC involved during this war? If not, is there a reason why they decided to stay away from this conflict?

Comment: There are innumerable silly WWII analogies that could be made here...

Answer (score 2):

There is no evidence that the Americans were involved in either of Britain's wars.  For the most part, Wizarding communities seem to operate in isolation. The only non-British participants in the Second War were Fleur Delacour in the Order, and Igor Karkaroff among the Death Eaters. The Ministry does have a Department of International Magic Cooperation, the duties of which are listed on the Harry Potter Wiki:

> to set standards for trade, create regulations for things like cauldron thickness, interpret international magical law, work with Department of Magical Games and Sports on the Triwizard Tournament, be present at the International Confederation of Wizards, British Seats.

There is no mention of coopoeration for emergencies, disasters, or war. In her entry on Pottermore regarding MACUSA's history, Rowling writes that during the American War for Independence wizards debated whether to join their countrymen or not. MACUSA contacted the British Ministry:

> Messengers were sent to the Ministry of Magic in London to ask whether they intended to fight. A four-word message returned: 'Sitting this one out.' The MACUSA President McGilliguddy’s famous response was even shorter: **‘Mind you do.’**

(Pottermore, Oct. 6, 2016)

This shows that some American wizards would have been willing to fight against  British wizards, even for a Muggle war. Countries will collaborate to maintain secrecy or play Quidditch, but when it comes to war Britain was on its own.

Comment: JKR's quote is quite interesting. It is quite possible that since the British wizards rejected to help the Americans, they would have done the same.  I guess it would be better if you could add your source to it.